What does error "Session terminated, protocol error. No Minecraft Add-Ons found" mean in Minecraft Debugger for Visual Studio Code
When using the "Minecraft Bedrock Edition Debugger" extension for Visual Studio Code, and executing the "Debug With Minecraft" command, I get the following error message...

Session terminated, protocol error. No Minecraft Add-Ons found

What does that error message mean?
And what's the typical remedy?
The game sees my manifest.json file appears to properly parse it.  The game allows me to add my script to a newly created world.  When the game starts I don't see any error messages related to the script.  I don't seem to be getting the "All systems GO!" message I wanted to display though.
My files are as follows
manifest.json
{
    "format_version" : 2,
    "header" : {
        "description" :"Gives you the power of the dark wizard",
        "name" : "Dark Wizard add on pack",
        "uuid" : "817e20e8-bef1-4d77-8ff0-88b14e0fcfda",
        "version" : [1,0,0],
        "min_engine_version" : [1, 20, 30]
    },
    "modules" : [
        {
            "description" : "Gives you the power of the dark wizard",
            "type" : "script",
            "uuid" : "7c1970f3-5784-4e85-b275-1af25e037886",
            "version" : [1,0,0],
            "entry" : "scripts/main.js"
        }
    ],
    "dependencies" : [
        {
            "module_name" : "@minecraft/server",
            "version" : [1,9,0]
        },{
            "module_name" : "@minecraft/vanilla-data",
            "version" : [1,21,44]
        }
    ]
}

scripts/main.js
import {
    world,
    system,
    EntityIsSaddledComponent
  } from "@minecraft/server";
import * as vanilla from "@minecraft/vanilla-data"

function mainTick() {
  if (system.currentTick === 400) {
    world.sendMessage("All systems GO!");
  }
  system.run(mainTick);
}

system.run(mainTick);

.vscode/launch.json
{
    "version" : "0.3.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type" : "minecraft-js",
            "request": "attach",
            "name" : "Debug With Minecraft",
            "mode" : "connect",            
            "targetModuleUuid": "7c1970f3-5784-4e85-b275-1af25e037886",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/",
            "port" : 19144
        }
    ] }

